# Checking session expiration in the browser

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, session, cookies

I am working on an app that must use session timeouts.

The problem is that users regularly miss the session timeout and lose data. I already implemented a small session keeper in javascript that will renew the session every one minute if there has been some activity in the browser, but users are still somehow losing data (assumably they are half filling out a form, walking away from their machines and coming back after the session has expired and submitting the form.)

I would like to find some way to warn them that their session has expired. The problem is that I can't figure out exactly how to do it. I can't check the expiration of the session cookie in javascript, because it's an HttpOnly cookie, and if I do some kind of AJAX request to check the status of the session, it will automatically set a new expiration for the session.

Can anyone see a way around these obstacles?

Comment: Every time you set or refresh the session, add a setTimeout that will alert the user in 1 minute, like so `setTimeout(function() { alert("Your session is expired.");}, 6000);`

Comment: If they submit a form, and your server-side logic decides their session has expired – then why not simply take that data they submitted and put it into a new session, and redirect them to the login form? After they have successfully logged in again, you take that data from the session, and process it …

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer about checking session time-outs... but I've found [garlic.js](http://garlicjs.org/) to help when I'm worried about users losing their work in forms. Basically, it's a JS library that takes care of saving form data in the user's browser's local storage until the form is submitted. So that, in case the browser closes or the session expires, the data is not lost. So this may be a good backup solution for the from data getting lost part.

**UPDATE**:

What I typically do to avoid form submission after session timeout is to set a javascript timer that will auto redirect the user to a session expired page (with an easy log in again button) a few seconds after the typical session timeout length. (You could reset this timer with your AJAX polling when there is activity within the page.) This combined with garlic.js, combined with "deep dive" functionality (whereby you store authenticated URLs in the session when they're accessed so that after a timeout and log back in you return the user to the last page they were on) creates a pretty seamless timeout, log-in, resume where you left off scenario.

Comment: Cool!  I hadn't heard of garlic, the only problem there is that it clears localStorage when you submit the form, whereas the problem case I have is when the user submits the form after the session has expired.  That did inspire me to write a little code toying around with localStorage to solve the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer to include a bit more on how I'd handle the "submit the form after the session has expired" thing. For some reason I didn't get that that was the problem the first time around, sorry!